# Wordpress/Lumberjack - 404 page displayed when trying to access route

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting started using [Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/) and [Lumberjack](https://docs.lumberjack.rareloop.com/the-basics/http-requests) and I'm trying to simply get a "Hello World" example working.  So far no success.  I've added a couple of routes and created a controller but whenever I go to example.com/Test or /hello-world I get a 404 error.

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Within my Wordpress theme `routes.php` file I have:

```
<?php

use Rareloop\Lumberjack\Facades\Router;
use Zend\Diactoros\Response\HtmlResponse;

Router::get('Test', function () {});

Router::get('hello-world', function () {
   return new HtmlResponse('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
});
```

I also created a test controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Rareloop\Lumberjack\Http\Controller as BaseController;

class TestController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter('wp_title', function ($title) {
            return 'TEST TITLE';
        });
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by including an `.htaccess` in the root of my project folder with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```